# Java to C#: HashMap, Map and Queue

Tags: c#, java, .net, generics, porting

I have to translate some code from Java to C#.

```
private Map[] M = new HashMap[2];
private Queue[] q = new LinkedList[2];
```

So, I know I have to use Dictionary instead of HashMap but I have some problems dealing with the generics in .Net.  Any ideas?

Here is what i have in the init method:

```
 M[0] = new HashMap<State, State>();
 M[1] = new HashMap<State, State>();
 q[0] = new LinkedList<State>();
 q[1] = new LinkedList<State>();
```

where `State` is a custom class.

The following code does not work:

```
private Queue<State>[] q = new LinkedList<State>[2];
```

Comment: What version of C# do you need to use?

Comment: @Oded I am using C# 4.0 which comes with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: And what types should these collections contain?

Comment: You can use Generics only if all the items in your collection are of the same type - is this the case with your code?

Comment: `code` M[0] = new HashMap<State, State>();
       M[1] = new HashMap<State, State>();
       q[0] = new LinkedList<State>();
       q[1] = new LinkedList<State>(); `code`   Where State is a custom class which i suppose it means they will be of the same type. Sorry for the formatting of the post.

Comment: If you want to add detail to your question, please edit it.

Comment: OK, now explain what the problem you are having are.

Comment: private Queue<State>[] q = new LinkedList<State>[2];   This does not work.

Comment: What do you think this line of code is supposed to do?

Comment: Not quite sure what's the purpose of this, maybe some polymorphism trick that i do not get it. I think i am going to replace with `code` private Queue<State>[] q = new Queue<State>[2]; `code` and pray this will not effect the rest of the code :D

Comment: What are you trying to make? A queue of `State` objects? A queue of linked lists? A queue of linked list nodes? An array of queues? Your examples don't say whether the code you've written are working Java or attempts at C# that don't work. Tell us *in words* what data structures you're trying to create, and we can help you out.

Comment: To avoid clutter, I'm adding this as a comment: Overall C#'s Collections API design is significantly different from Java's and is more *simplified* (to be nice) than one might expect, especially when coming from Java background. Of course the basics are always the basics and .NET's class design is built to match that platform so this is merely expectable, not some horrible era in API design.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't compiling because in Java, a `Queue` is an interface that the class `LinkedList<T>` implements.  The assignment operator passes because a LinkedList *is* a Queue.

In C# `Queue<T>` and `LinkedList<T>` are both classes, and neither is derived from the other.  The end result is that you can make it

```
Queue<State>[] q = new Queue<State>[2];
```

and that is probably not going to cause you any problems, provided that later on in the Java it's not trying to cast those Queues back to LinkedLists or other weirdness, and provided you can map all of the Java Queue methods to C# Queue methods.

More Reading:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx